# Validating form and sending a confirmation email on submission

Tags: php, mysql, forms, validation, email

I am creating an admin page, where the admin person can create users accounts for people. The idea is, that once the form is completed, when clicking 'Submit' an email must be sent to the user (containing the ID and name of account selected). In the same action, the form must also first be validated and if there are any errors with the validation the data should not be submitted to the database. None of this is happening though and I cannot figure out why.

- The email is not being sent,
- the data is inserted in the database even if there are errors and upon loading the page,
- errors are displayed for all form fields even though the submit button have not been clicked.

***Any help, advice or links to possible sources/tutorials would be greatly appreciated.***

Below is my code: (Note that I am only working in PHP, HTML and using a MYSQL database)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        User Registration
    </title>
    <?PHP


    include_once 'includes\functions.php';
    connect();

    error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);


//Assign variables
    $accounttype=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['accounttype']);
    $sname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sname']);
    $fname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']);
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $address = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['address']);
    $contact_flag = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['contact_flag']);


//Validating form(part1)        

    $error='';          


//Connect to database                   
        $SQL=
            "INSERT INTO student 
                        (
                            sname,fname,email, address, contact_flag
                        ) 
            VALUES 
                        (

                        '$sname', '$fname', '$email', '$address', '$contact_flag' 
                        )
            ";
        if (!mysql_query($SQL))
            {
                print'Error: '.mysql_error();
            }

        mysql_close($db_handle);
//Validate form(part 2)
    if (isset($_POST['sname'], $_POST['fname'],$_POST['email'],$_POST['address']));
        {
            $errors=array();


                $accounttype= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['accounttype']);
                $sname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sname']);
                $fname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']);
                $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
                $address = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['address']);
                $contact_flag = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['contact_flag']);

// form validation
                        if(strlen(mysql_real_escape_string($sname))<1)
                        {
                            $errors[]='Your surname is too short!';
                        }

                        if(strlen(mysql_real_escape_string($fname))<1)
                        {
                            $errors[]='Please insert you full first name';
                        }


                        if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)===FALSE)
                        {
                            $errors[]='Please insert your valid email address';
                        }
                        if(strlen(mysql_real_escape_string($address))<8)
                        {
                            $errors[]='Please insert your postal address';
                        }

                            echo'<pre>';
                            print_r($errors);
                            echo'</pre>';
        }


//confirmation email

    // Subject of confirmation email.
        $conf_subject = 'Registration confirmed';

    // Who should the confirmation email be from?
        $conf_sender = 'PHP Project <my@email.com>';

    $msg = $_POST['fname'] . ",\n\nThank you for registering. \n\n You registered for account:".$accounttype."\n\n Your account number:".mysql_insert_id;

        mail( $_POST['email'], $conf_subject, $msg, 'From: ' . $conf_sender );



   ?>
</head>
<body>


    </br>
    <form name ="form0" Method="POST" Action="<?PHP echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    </br>
        </br>
        <b>Select the course you wish to register for:</b></br>
                <select   name="accounttype">
                    <?PHP query() ?>

                </select>   
                    <?PHP close() ?>


    </form>


    <form name ="form1" Method="POST" Action="<?PHP echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">

        </br>
        </br>
        <Input type ="" Value = "Surname" Name = "sname"></br>
        <Input type ="" Value = "First name" Name = "fname"></br>
        <b>Email:</b> <Input type ="" Value = "" Name = "email"></br>
        <b>Address:</b> </br>
        <textarea rows="4" cols="20" Name="address">Please provide your postal address here </textarea></br>
        <b>Tick to receive confinmation email:</b> <Input type ="checkbox" Value = "1" Name = "contact_flag"></br>

        <Input type = "Submit" Value="Submit">

    </form>





</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why assigning variables, twice?

Comment: For some reason the data would not send to the database if I only inserted it once. I kept getting errors indicating that the variables are not assigned. But if you can tell me what I am doing wrong I'd be happy to remove the additional script!!

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?PHP
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    include_once 'includes\functions.php';
    connect();

// your rest of the code

        mail( $_POST['email'], $conf_subject, $msg, 'From: ' . $conf_sender );

}

   ?>
```

and keep this code out of the `<html>` tag but before it

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you!! It makes sense and I must admit that I am really starting to feel like there is light at the end of the tunnel! I did as you recommended, and now I have the next issue. Suddenly, the only thing displaying on my page is the drop-down menu, and nothing else. I will however continue investigating and let you know if I come up with anything...

Answer (score 0):

and if you want to stick to PHP only then one error i can see is

```
that you have kept the **validation code below the `INSERT`**
```

query which means that the **insert** query will be executed first **which will store the data in the database first** and then it will go for the validation...**so keep your validation code above the INSERT statement..**
 and **second thing** use `exit()` method  after vaidating every field if it gives you error...it will stop executing rest of the php code if any field gives the error during validation....and so it will also **prevent the data from storing into the database if it finds exit method whenever an error is found** eg

```
 if(strlen(mysql_real_escape_string($sname))<1)
                        {
                            $errors[]='Your surname is too short!';
                           echo '//whatever you want to echo';
                           exit();
                        }

                        if(strlen(mysql_real_escape_string($fname))<1)
                        {

                            $errors[]='Please insert you full first name';
                         echo '//whatever you want to echo';
                         exit();
                        }
```

Comment: He is asking for a PHP validation... what happens if the browser is old?

Comment: Thank you so much for shedding some light on my problem!! I removed one set of assigned variables. Then moved the form validation section up so it appears AFTER assigning the variables but BEFORE the 'INSERT'** code and I added the exit method as suggested. However, now I am getting the following a whole lot of "Notice: Undefined index: sname ..." and the rest of the page is blank i.o.w no form. What could the reason be?? (BTW this also kept happening before, but stopped once I assigned the variables a second time.

Comment: first of all give a name to the submit button you have made... using name="submit" and then keep all of your php code except the php code which is included in the forms in the if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {// keep all your php code here}....this code will execute only if you have submitted the form....the problem with your current code is that the code is searching for $_POST['something'] even when you have not submitted the form

Answer (score 0):

At first, your query gets executed before you validate your form.

Move your SQL after your

```
echo'<pre>';
print_r($errors);
echo'</pre>';
```

and surround it with

```
if(!$errors){}
```

This will prevent your query from being executed if there are any errors.
(You can also delete your first assignement of your variables)

Concerning your email problem, test your connection with a simple message

```
mail('your@email.com', 'subject', 'message');
```

If you get any error, probably your mailserver isn't set up right